# why don't abstract members be marked as public automatically?

Tags: c#

```
abstract class mybase
{
    public int a, b, result;

    public int Multi()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class derived : mybase
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        derived de = new derived();

        Console.WriteLine("Result of 3 * 5 = {0}", de.Multi());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public int Multi()
    {
        a = 3;
        b = 5;
        return (result = a * b);
    }
}
```

If I change the line:

```
public int a, b, result;
```

to

```
 int a, b, result;
```

it will not work.

My question is: Why don't variables a, b, result be marked as "public abstract members" automatically?

Comment: In the example you give, the changed line was exactly the same as the original.  What did you change the public modifier to?

Comment: A class is `private` by default.  If you don't mark the class as `public`, then the variables within that class will also be `private`, unless otherwise declared.  In your example above, the class is `abstract`, but not `public`.

Comment: @dubstylee the default accessibility of anything is the most narrow valid accessibility; that's not always `private`.  For example, non-nested classes cannot be `private`, so they must be `internal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not *abstract* members, they are [Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you don't specify any access modifier with them then they will be treated as `private`, which means they are accessible inside the class *only* and you can't access them outside the class.

So this line:

```
int a, b, result;
```

means

```
private int a, b, result;
```

Making them `public` would allow other classes to use these fields. If you only want these fields to be accessible in the inherited class then use `protected`.